# Is there any quick way to know if a web service supports SOAP or REST?

Tags: web-services, rest, soap

I would like to know if there is any quick test, hint or tip that tells you whether a Web service supports SOAP and/or REST requests. Maybe something written in the WSDL ?

As an example I'm trying to call this web service described here. I can see that there are some SOAP words on it, but is it possible to know whether it supports REST ? Thanks

https://www3.bcb.gov.br/sgspub/JSP/sgsgeral/FachadaWSSGS.wsdl

Comment: If you have a WSDL file, operations invoked on methods contained in the contract are SOAP based. Although some REST frameworks provide a similar approach like WSDL, WADL, this is not that popular as it often contradicts the RESTful idea of self-describing services. SOAP services often use HTTP as protocol (especially POST operation), but don't have to, REST is no protocol but an architectural style which utilizes the full range of HTTP methods and standards - therefore your question does not make much sense IMO.

Comment: If it is a WSDL it is SOAP. If you see WADL, RAML then you are using Rest. However you really need to understand that these services are fundamentally different in all aspects.